# Issue with Like Box not pulling current data

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have been using Like Box to show our company Facebook feeds on our company portal. The feeds stopped updating on March 24 but we have more current post. Everything seems to be working but current feeds stopped?
Did something change with Like Box? Below the “Old Code” is what I have been using, below that is what I got from the “Get Code” today which has the same result… seem to work but no current post.
Old Code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPowerTradingRadio&amp;width=292&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=427" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="border: currentColor; width: 292px; height: 427px; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

New Like Box Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/PowerTradingRadio" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no posts made from the Online Trading Academy (PowerTradingRadio) account after March 24th. All the other posts on the wall are made by individuals and are not shown in the public like box.

If you are the owner of the page, you can go to the group page, edit page, click on your settings, and click on 'always comment or post on your page as PowerTradingRadio' or in the top right change your account to use PowerTradingRadio before posting.